# material-ui: AppBar: strategy for restricting an image height to AppBar height?

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-ui

can anyone provide guidance around an idiomatic way to place an image in an AppBar and have it be restricted to the standard material height (e.g. 64px for a desktop)?

i'm currently using `material-ui@next` (`1.0.0-beta.2` currently).

i have found that something like:

```
<AppBar>
  <Toolbar>
    <IconButton color="contrast" aria-label="Menu">
      <MenuIcon />
    </IconButton>
    <img src={logo} style={{height: 64}}/>
    <Typography type="title" color="inherit">
      React Scratch
    </Typography>
  </Toolbar>
</AppBar>
```

works well.

the actual logo is a png file with a height greater than 64, so if i don't ratchet it down, it expands the height of the AppBar out of Material spec.

in the current master branch version of `src/styles` there is a `getMuiTheme.js` which seems to [deliver this height readily](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/13548d80b9bc74a990262e6d3cd7e66df79950ea/src/styles/getMuiTheme.js#L35), but in the `@next` version i am looking at, that file doesn't even exist and tbh, i can't easily determine how that height is being set anymore.

i found that the AppBar is currently being [renovated for composability](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/773), so that churn might make it challenging to answer this question, but just in case anyone has a good handle on this, i figured i would toss the question out there.

thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In all cases I've seen, an AppBar is implemented with a Toolbar as it's first child.  The Toolbar's stylesheet dictates it's height based on the breakpoints defined in the theme.

Take a look here: https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/v1-beta/src/Toolbar/Toolbar.js

You can use a similar approach to define a stylesheet with a class for your AppBar images that varies the height for the applicable breakpoints.  Then when rendering the component, apply the class to your image.

Note: if you use the withStyles HOC, as is done in the Toolbar, AppBar etc, the classes defined in that stylesheet will be available through a prop named classes.

You are right about the AppBar's need for composability, but that issue has not been solved yet, and this is the beta branch anyway.  When it is solved, there should be a better solution that would be worth migrating towards.

I hope this answer helps.  I would have added code samples but I am answering from my phone while waiting in a grocery store parking lot.  If I get a chance I will update this answer.

Here's one approach, duplicating the styles in a new reusable component:

```
import createStyleSheet from 'material-ui/styles/createStyleSheet';
import withStyles from 'material-ui/styles/withStyles';

// define these styles once, if changes are needed because of a change
// to the material-ui beta branch, the impact is minimal
const styleSheet = createStyleSheet('ToolbarImage', theme => ({
    root: {
        height: 56,
        [`${theme.breakpoints.up('xs')} and (orientation: landscape)`]: {
            height: 48,
        },
        [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
            height: 64,
        },
    },
}));

// a reusable component for any image you'd need in a toolbar/appbar
const ToolbarImage = (props) => {
    const { src, classes } = this.props;
    return (
        <img src={src} className={classes.root} />
    );
};

// this higher order component uses styleSheet to add
// a classes prop that contains the name of the classes
export default withStyles(styleSheet)(ToolbarImage);
```

Another approach is to add the standard toolbar heights to the theme as [business variables](https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/customization/themes#business-variables), override the `root` class [for all Toolbars](https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/customization/themes#customizing-all-instances-of-a-component-type) so that it makes use of them, and use the theme whenever you need to reference them again:

```
  // define the standard heights in one place
  const toolbarHeights = {
    mobilePortrait: 56,
    mobileLandscape: 48,
    tabletDesktop: 64,
  };

  // create the theme as you normally would, but add the heights
  let theme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: createPalette({
      primary: blue,
      accent: pink,
    }),
    standards: {
      toolbar: {
        heights: toolbarHeights,
      },
    },
  });

  // recreate the theme, overriding the toolbar's root class
  theme = createMuiTheme({
    ...theme,
    overrides: {
      MuiToolbar: {
        // Name of the styleSheet
        root: {
          position: 'relative',
          display: 'flex',
          alignItems: 'center',
          minHeight: theme.standards.toolbar.heights.mobilePortrait,
          [`${theme.breakpoints.up('xs')} and (orientation: landscape)`]: {
            minHeight: theme.standards.toolbar.heights.mobileLandscape,
          },
          [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
            minHeight: theme.standards.toolbar.heights.tabletDesktop,
          },
        },
      },
    },
  });
```

Then you can reference these heights in any stylesheet you create because they're part of the theme.

**UPDATED FOLLOWING THE RELEASE OF 1.0.0-beta.11:**

There is now a toolbar mixin available on the theme that provides the toolbar minHeight for each breakpoint.  If you need to style an element relative to the standard height of the AppBar component, you can use this object to build your own styles:

```
const toolbarRelativeProperties = (property, modifier = value => value) => theme =>
  Object.keys(theme.mixins.toolbar).reduce((style, key) => {
    const value = theme.mixins.toolbar[key];
    if (key === 'minHeight') {
      return { ...style, [property]: modifier(value) };
    }
    if (value.minHeight !== undefined) {
      return { ...style, [key]: { [property]: modifier(value.minHeight) } };
    }
    return style;
  }, {});
```

In this example, `toolbarRelativeProperties` returns a function that will return an object that can be spread into your style object.  It addresses the simple case of setting a specified property to a value that is based on the AppBar height.

A simple usage example would be the generation of a dynamic CSS expression for height calculation, which is depending on the standard height of the AppBar:

```
const componentStyle = theme => ({
  root: {
    height: toolbarRelativeProperties('height', value => `calc(100% - ${value}px)`)(theme)
  }
});
```

The generated style definition might look like this:

```
{
  height: 'calc(100% - 56px)',
  '@media (min-width:0px) and (orientation: landscape)': {
    height: 'calc(100% - 48px)'
  },
  '@media (min-width:600px)': {
    height: 'calc(100% - 64px)'
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks ken, that explains how the height of the `AppBar` is determined (height of the `ToolBar` if i understand correctly). I guess if my goal is to add an image into the `AppBar`, then that image would be a child of the `ToolBar` as well. Would it be possible to get a reference to the parent `ToolBar`s `classes` object, so i might reference those styles from there instead of specifying similar in my "AppBarImage" component?

Comment: You can certainly pass the classes prop, or any of the classes contained therein, to any child of the Toolbar.  The problem is that the root class does more than you need it to.  You may need to define a new component with its own set of classes, something like ToolBarImage, that you use whenever you need to place an image within a toolbar.

Comment: thanks ken, yeah, i likely wouldn't want to pass `classes` as is from `ToolBar` to `ToolBarImage`, but maybe use portions of it. i'm sure i'm being a dunce, but i'm having an issue getting a reference to the `classes` prop of the `ToolBar` to pass down to one of it's children. i tried using a `ref` function on `ToolBar`, but the ref didn't have a `classes` prop when i looked at it.

Comment: Take a look at the example I've just added to the answer.  It should help you.

Comment: thanks for the code sample ken! i think that is a viable option. i was hoping to be able to grab some of the details from an existing component so as to keep things dry (i.e. not hardcode 64 in more than one place), and i'm still unclear as to whether that approach would be viable as well. if i was implementing in something like sass, i might place 64 in a variable and refer back to that where appropriate, so i was grasping for a similar strategy here. perhaps part of that challenge is working around strategies taken by material-ui (e.g. if 64 was in the theme object somewhere)

Comment: I've added another example that may get you where you need to be.  Material-UI allows you to do two things that get you there: 1. you can add anything you want to the theme 2. you can override any component's class.  Take a look at the second example in the updated answer.

Comment: @tony_k not sure if you're still interested in this issue, but there is a new feature in the latest release of material-ui that would make things a bit easier (and would require less maintenance than my other suggestions).

Comment: thanks @ken-gregory, that is more like what i was originally looking for. appreciate the update!

Comment: @KenGregory thank you for this very useful snippet! In the 1.0.0b11 sample, I think you meant _spread_ rather than _deconstructed_.

I'm also unsure of why you implemented it as a function that generates a function that is dependant on the theme, because I don't see the usefulness of being able to vary the theme between calls.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPaour The 1.0.0-beta.11 example allows you to use the toolbar mixin to style elements based on toolbar height.  So it isn't changing the theme, it is returning an object that is based on an aspect of the existing theme.  This object can be spread (thank you) into a set of styles that you're defining and it is especially useful if you need to position or size some element in consideration of a fixed toolbar.